# How to add functions in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new in firebase and I created a sample project on it. As I want to know the functionality of functions in command prompt. How it's done
after Node.js installation? What are the procedure for installation?

Comment: You need to provide more information on what you are trying to achieve with firebase, and the error message you get. If you are just getting started, consider going through the official tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try watch good this** [Getting Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ)

Comment: Welcome No problem

Answer (score 1):

For me this documentation helped a lot https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started.

Comment: after firebase init command what are the step to follow to create functions